# When adding two short numbers

Tags: c, variables, int, short

Really simple question here. I have a really simple program for adding two numbers and printing out the sum of those numbers (below). When running the program, it works as expected and prints out 40 000 for 20 000 + 20 000. But when I change int a, b and sum to **short** a,b and sum, I get -25 536 as an answer. Anyone who can explain why this happens? I have an idea, but would love to hear it from someone who knows it. Thanks for reading.

```
int a, b, sum;

a = 20000;  b = 20000;  sum = a+b;
printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, sum);
```

Comment: The maximum value of `short` on your implementation is `32767`.

Comment: you could try `unsigned short` if you want the 65535 max ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your system, `short` is presumably 16 bits, so the range of values is `-32768` to `32767`. `20000 + 20000` is larger that the maximum value, so this causes overflow, which results in undefined behavior.

If you change to `unsigned short`, the range becomes `0` to `65525`, and the addition will work. In addition, overflow is well-defined with `unsigned` integers, it simply wraps around using modular arithmetic, e.g. `(unsigned short)65535 + 2 = 1`.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum value of a signed short is 32767

In binary, this is a 16-bit number, rather than the 32 bit number (as is the case with ints). Because it's signed, it is represented as follows:

```
0 11111 11111 11111
```

If you add 1 to that, it becomes

```
1 00000 00000 00000
```

Which is back to -32768

You probably get the idea.